# PHP Warning :Division by zero

Tags: php

When I try to see my average scores for my table labeled tools, I keep getting this error
Warning: Division by zero in /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/Exercise5/showResults_step7.php on line 167
SUM for CSS: and AVE = nan

I changed the name of my project with XXXX's for confidential reasons

My lecture video had my professor doing this same things as I did below so I do not see why I am getting this error

```
 echo '  SUM for CSS: ' . $firstrow[0] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[0] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br>';
           echo '  SUM for Filezilla: ' . $firstrow[1] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[1] / $rows, 2) .
           '<br>';
           echo '  SUM for HTML: ' . $firstrow[2] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[2] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for SurveyMonkey: ' . $firstrow[3] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[3] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for Pixlr: ' . $firstrow[4] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[4] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for MySQLworkbench: ' . $firstrow[5] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[5] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for Atom: ' . $firstrow[6] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[6] / $rows, 2) .
           '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for Screencast: ' . $firstrow[7] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[7] / $rows, 2) .
           '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for Python: ' . $firstrow[8] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[8] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br><hr>';
           echo '  SUM for Googlesheets: ' . $firstrow[9] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[9] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br><hr>';
           // add closing div tag
           echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the value of $rows in line 167?

```
echo ' SUM for CSS: ' . $firstrow[0] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[0] / $rows, 2) // <= ¿whats the value of $rows here?
```

cause if it's 0 that could be the problem.

Comment: there is $row on line 167 there is    echo '<div class=\'resultStyle\'>'; on that line

Comment: could u post the full code pls?

Comment: echo '<div class=\'resultStyle\'>';
           // display SUM values and Average with is SUM / $rows (the latter computed further up)
           echo '  SUM for CSS: ' . $firstrow[1] . ' and AVE = ' . number_format($firstrow[1] / $rows, 2) .
            '<br>';

Comment: are u sure this variable has something inside? $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: no it is stated as such : $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: my peer advised me to put an echo statement underneath it and see what happens, so I put echo "<h2>". $rows. "</h2>"; underneath the above row of mysqli_num_row($result);

Comment: $sql="your sql stmt";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($rows >0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

//do all the calcaulation and pringing process
}
}